# scipy equivalent for MATLAB spy

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I have been porting code for an isomap algorithm from MATLAB to Python. I am trying to visualize the sparsity pattern using the spy function.

MATLAB command:

```
spy(sparse(A));
drawnow;
```

Python command:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.spy(scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(A))
plt.show()
```

I am not able to reproduce the MATLAB result in Python using the above command. Using the command with only A in non-sparse format gives quite similar result to MATLAB. But it's taking quite long (A being 2000-by-2000). What would be the MATLAB equivalent of a sparse function for scipy?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe it's your version of `matplotlib` that makes trouble, as for me `scipy.sparse` and `matplotlib.pylab` work well together.

See sample code below that produces the 'spy' plot attached.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import scipy.sparse as sps
A = sps.rand(10000,10000, density=0.00001)
M = sps.csr_matrix(A)
plt.spy(M)
plt.show()

# Returns here '1.3.0'
matplotlib.__version__
```

This gives this plot: [image]

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that the error was in my code for creating the A matrix in Python.One quick question. The blue squares produced are the non-zeros right?

Answer (score 9):

I just released [betterspy](https://github.com/nschloe/betterspy), which arguably does a better job here. Install with

```
pip install betterspy
```

and run with

```py
import betterspy
from scipy import sparse

A = sparse.rand(20, 20, density=0.1)
betterspy.show(A)
betterspy.write_png("out.png", A)
```

[image]

Comment: looks like a nice complement for matplotlib. Is it possible to use axis properties, such as, `ax.set_xticklabels(...)` for `betterspy.show()`? Nice job by the way.

Comment: Simply use `betterspy.plot(A)`, set whatever you want on `gca()`, and then `pyplot.show()` the image.

Comment: Oh boi, works like a charm. Didn't saw that method on readme file. I suggest and improvement on documentation. Thanks. @Nitin this should be the accepted answer. Here a quick example: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, betterspy as bspy, scipy.sparse as sps; A=sps.rand(5,5, density=.4); bspy.plot(A); ax=plt.gca(); ax.set_xticklabels(['','a','b','c','d','e']); plt.show()`

Answer (score 6):

With smaller markers:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import scipy.sparse as sps
import scipy.io
import sys
A=scipy.io.mmread(sys.argv[1])
pl.spy(A,precision=0.01, markersize=1)
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

See [matspy](https://pypi.org/project/matspy/).

```
pip install matspy
```

Large matrices are no problem, a spy plot of tens of millions of nonzeros takes less than half a second. A small example:

```py
from matspy import spy
import scipy

n = 9000
A = scipy.sparse.random(n, n, density=0.001) + scipy.sparse.eye(n)

spy(A)
```

[image: matspy output]

If you want to modify the plot further, use `fig, ax = matspy.spy_to_mpl(A)` instead.