# matshow with sparse matrices

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

How can you visualize the sparsity pattern of a large sparse matrix?

The matrix is too large to fit in memory as a dense array, so I have it in csr_matrix format. When I try pylab's matshow with it, I get the following error:

ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Thoughts?

e.g.:

```
import pylab as pl
import scipy.sparse as sp
from random import randint

mat = sp.lil_matrix( (4000,3000), dtype='uint8' )
for i in range(1000):
    mat[randint(0,4000),randint(0,3000)] = randint(0,10)

pl.figure()
pl.matshow(mat)
```

Comment: can you show use some example code that generates this error?  Suspect you will be better off drawing patches by hand than using `matshow`/`imshow` (which will, I think, fill your sparse matrix).

Comment: possible duplicate of [scipy equivalent for MATLAB spy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651869/scipy-equivalent-for-matlab-spy)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`matshow` works on dense arrays. For sparse arrays you can use `spy`:

```
import scipy.sparse as sps
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = sps.rand(1000, 1000, density=0.001, format='csr')

plt.spy(a)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you ladies and gentlemen.