# Plotting an adjacency matrix with color coded nodes

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot a 30x30 adjacency matrix in such a way that each node colour corresponds to whether that point/node belongs to 1 or 0 value in a 1-D array having 1 and 0 values.

So here is an example of a adjacency matrix:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,
         1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,
         0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,
         1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,
         0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

And here is a one dim array which has 30 values corresponding to whether the point belongs to 1 or 0 cluster.

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I want to plot each nodes in my adjacency matrix (which in my understanding is each row in the adjacency matrix) and colour code them accordingly if they belong to 1 or 0 cluster. So if ith row of adjacency matrix has ith value of 1-d array as 1So all nodes belonging to 1 cluster(having 1 in the corresponding index of 1-d are, then create a node with colour black , else if ith row of adjacency matrix has ith value of 1-d array as 0 then colour the nodes as red. And then connect all such nodes with edges based on the relationship present in the adjacency matrix.

I know kind of how to do it in networkx lib but that lib doesn't give me the right position of nodes layout. So am looking for a solution in matplotlib.

Comment: So you want to plot the graph or an image of the adjacency matrix?

Comment: I want to plot the graph with nodes and edges and each node colour coded as per the cluster(1,0) it belongs to based on the 1D array given

Comment: [this may give you some hint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22965622/832621)

Comment: Hi Thanks. But that one is plotting each cell A(i,j) as a point(white or black). Mine is like each row in an adjacency matrix is basically a node right. So if ith row has 1 in the ith row of 1-d array, then colour the node as say black else if ith row has ith value of 1-d array as 0 then colour the node as red. Also show the edges.

Answer (score 1):

you can use graphviz to draw the graph here is the code to create the dot file:

```
a = np.array([[...]])
nodes = np.array([...])
colors = ["red", "green"]

graph = ""

for i, c in enumerate(nodes):
    graph += 'n{index}[label="{index}" color={color}];'.format(index=i, color=colors[c])

for start, end in zip(*np.where(a)):
    if start > end:
        graph += 'n{start} -- n{end};'.format(start=start, end=end)

graph = "graph {%s}" % graph
```

then you can call "graphviz" to create the graph, here is the IPython magic I use:

https://gist.github.com/cjdrake/7982333

the result is:

[image]