# How to print whole sparse matrix?

Tags: python, scipy

I want to print the whole matrix. When I print X it tells me location where values are stored expcept zeros. Can I print whole matrix including zeros?

```
X = sparse.csr_matrix(1./2.*np.array([[0.,1.],[1.,0.]]))
print(X)
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22965622/832621) might be helpful. It shows how to visualize such matrix without converting it to a dense matrix (which usually is not possible due to memory constraints)

Answer (score 9):

You can convert the sparse matrix to dense (i.e. regular numpy matrix) and then print the dense representation. For this use the method [todense](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.todense.html).

Sample code:

```
X = sparse.csr_matrix(1./2.*np.array([[0.,1.],[1.,0.]]))
a = X.todense()
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just print. You can simply use toarray() method and convert it to an array. Similarly, you can also convert it into a data frame to perform any pandas operations using the pandas Dataframe() method.

```
X = sparse.csr_matrix(1./2.*np.array([[0.,1.],[1.,0.]]))
print(X.toarray())
X_df =pd.DataFrame(X.toarray())
X_df
```

Answer (score 1):

[matrepr](https://pypi.org/project/matrepr/) prints sparse matrices directly, without conversions to other formats:

```py
X = sparse.csr_matrix(1./2.*np.array([[0.,1.],[1.,0.]]))

from matrepr import mprint
mprint(X, fill_value=0.)
```

yields:

```
<2×2, 2 'float64' elements, csr>
     0    1
  ┌          ┐
0 │  0   0.5 │
1 │ 0.5   0  │
  └          ┘
```

For a more compact view with blank spaces instead of zeros, `mprint(X, title=None, indices=False)`:

```
┌          ┐
│      0.5 │
│ 0.5      │
└          ┘
```