# How to show the full scikit's sparse matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, scipy

I am vectorizing with tfidf:

```
X = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(df['string'].values)
```

I would like to se the whole matrix of the above code so I tried this:

```
print X.toarray()
```

And obtained this:

```
[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]
```

How can I write to some txt file or see the full matrix X?.

Comment: Do you want to see it with all the 0s, or would a list of non zero entries be better.  What is the size (shape) of this array?

Comment: Both could be nice to see how it looks, thanks!

Comment: There is an equivalent of the MATLAB `spy` function which plots an image of the sparsity of a sparse matrix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651869/scipy-equivalent-for-matlab-spy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can write it to a text file:

```
pd.DataFrame(X.toarray()).to_csv('bow.csv')
```

Keep in mind that it can have very high 'n', and might make for a very large `.txt`

Answer (score 1):

For interactive use, you can change the number of items to show

```
numpy.set_printoptions(edgeitems=1e9)
```

For saving to text files, use `numpy.savetxt(X.toarray())` or some other similar function.