# How to get constraints in matrix format from Gurobi/JuMP?

Tags: julia, linear-programming, gurobi, julia-jump

I have built an LP model in JuMP/Julia using Gurobi solver. I wish to visualize the constraints for checking the overall correctness of my model. In python, we can define a function help to visualize the constraints. Please follow the link below for pythons solution. How to get access to constraint matrix and visualize it in JuMP?

[Get constraints in matrix format from gurobipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647230/get-constraints-in-matrix-format-from-gurobipy)

Best,

NG

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to do that in Julia:

- [using Plotly](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/gallery/plotlyjs/generated/plotlyjs-ref032/)

  ```
  julia> using Plots
  julia> plotlyjs()
  julia> spy(A)
  ```
- [just using Plots](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/spy-function-for-large-sparse-matrices/11247)

  ```
  julia> using Plots
  julia> spy(A)
  ```