# How to retrieve non-zeroes using gurobipy?

Tags: python-3.x, gurobi

I am using gurobipy to read LP files. The command 
`model=gurobipy.read("name.lp", env=env)` gives me the number of rows, columns, and non-zeroes. However, I need to retrieve the number of non-zeroes. I don't believe there is a function that does this automatically (i.e. `model.getnonzeros()` )
Is there a way to obtain the non-zeros? How would I write python code to be able to do this if there isn't a built in function?

#### Consulted resources

- [Get constraints in matrix format from gurobipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647230/get-constraints-in-matrix-format-from-gurobipy)

Comment: Welcome to SO! May you  please elaborate a bit (by editing the question), (1) what LP files are, (2) what you already tried in terms of code snippets, plus (3) web-resources you consulted so far?

Comment: .LP files are linear program files read by gurobipy . I haven't tried anything in terms of code snippets. As far as web resources, I looked at the Gurobi reference manual and looked on stackoverflow as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out - perusing the Gurobi reference manual, in chapter 6, Python API overview, I see there is an attribute called "NumNZs" that can be called as:

print(model.getAttr("NumNZs"))

This will give the non-zeroes